# Having trouble deploying ad hoc testing version of iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm new to iOS development and I'm having a bit of an issue deploying something for my client to test. I am using XCode v4.3.2. I was given an xcode project, and asked to make some minor coding changes, mainly to get my feet wet. I made the changes, compiled the app, ran it in the emulator, it worked fine. I tethered my iPhone to the macbook and followed apple's instructions to set up my phone as the dev phone, ran it from the phone, no problems.

Now the part I need help with. The company has a development license with Apple. They sent me an invite through Apple, which I accepted, which generated an Apple dev license for me. The project I took over had a bunch of code signing keys associated with it, that were all expired, so I switched over the keys to the one that was generated for me. I archived the project, and then saved it for adhoc/enterprise, which generated a .ipa file. They tried to load the ipa onto an iPod Touch (which the project has previously worked on) and it generated an error saying that it didnt have entitlements.

I checked Stackoverflow and found an article that stated how to add entitlements, so I followed them, and now in Code Signing Entitlements (in the Build Settings) it says : [ProjectName].entitlements (where the [ProjectName] is the actual project name :) ). I reaarchived and sent to her, and she tried to load the new .ipa. Now on the sync, she gets "not installed on ipod because an unknown error occurred (0xE8003FFE)".

This is driving me nuts... what am I doing wrong? I have the device ID for her iPod, just in case, do I have to set up some specific "thing" for her as an adhoc tester? I figured it would just work.... Please help!

Comment: Everything seemed to be followed well. Just check while code-signing app, u r using proper provisioning profile & proper .plist file. I also presume that destination iPod is provisioned device on apple developer site.!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at

https://testflightapp.com/

It is an easier way to distribute builds to your clients and testers.

I use it regularly and it saves a lot of headache...

Comment: just upload the .ipa file on testflightapp and invite the users who you want it to be distributed to

Answer (score 0):

We use hockeyapp.net with great success.  We've been using this for quite some time and our clients love the simplicity of OTA beta distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Another company worth investigating is www.appblade.com. If you want a solution that blends iOS with Android and other platforms it works well. Testflight has been migrated into iTunes Connect.